# Choosing a tool for development: System Generator vs Xilinx ISE

Tags: fpga, xilinx, vhdl, tools, xilinx-system-generator

I am trying to make a an implementation of a vhdl design. It´s an application for signal processing. Does anyone know what is the fastest development tool Xilinx System Generator or Xilinx ISE.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Completing an entire FPGA design purely in system generator is likely to be very-hard to impossible, especially if you have to interface to external peripherals.

If you already have an FPGA framework developed which you want to drop a signal processing block into, then System Generator can be a good way to go.  You have all the abilities of Matlab behind you for verifying the design, whereas doing it in pure VHDL/Verilog makes the verification harder work.

For example, I developed an implementation of a common image-processing algorithm (a Shi-Tomasi corner detector) fairly quickly with System Generator.  But.... I had already built up the rest of the system (which was pretty big with embedded Microblazes, ram controllers etc) in EDK and with the ISE tools.

One thing System Generator makes very easy (which is a huge time saver IMO) is linking your block up to an EDK design. You just drag some blocks in for the registers and shared memory blocks and it sorts all the bus interfacing and creation of the files which tell EDK how to use it.  Even the SW boilerplate to access the registers.

Comment: What do you refer about IMO? What means IMO?

Comment: I´m using a small form factor board of Software Define Radio to perform my design.